# Continuous Integration workflow with docker swarm

Tags: continuous-integration, docker-compose, continuous-deployment, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Here's my setup, this output was taken from `docker-machine ls`. Using docker machine to provision the swarm.

```
NAME             ACTIVE      DRIVER         STATE     URL                          SWARM                     DOCKER    ERRORS
cluster-master   * (swarm)   digitalocean   Running   tcp://REDACTED:2376   cluster-master (master)   v1.11.1   
kv-store         -           digitalocean   Running   tcp://REDACTED:2376                              v1.11.1   
node-1           -           digitalocean   Running   tcp://REDACTED:2376   cluster-master            v1.11.1   
node-2           -           digitalocean   Running   tcp://REDACTED:2376   cluster-master            v1.11.1
```

Right now I'm searching for a way to setup my CI/CD workflow. Here is my initial idea:

1. Create an automatic build on docker hub (bitbucket)
2. Once changes are pushed, trigger build on docker hub
3. Testing will be done on docker hub (npm test)
4. Create a webhook on docker hub once build is success.
5. The webhook will point to my own application that will then push the changes to the swarm

**Questions:**

- Is it okay to run your testing on docker hub or should I rely on another service?
- If I will rely on another service what is your recommended service?
- My main problem is pushing the changes to the docker swarm. Should I setup my docker-swarm on a remote machine and host the application there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the process all looks fine. Where it gets complicated is managing the deployed production containers.

> Is it okay to run your testing on docker hub or should I rely on
>     another service?

Yes it should be fine to run tests on docker hub assuming you don't need further integration tests.

I need to integrate my containers with amazon services and have a fairly non-standard deployment so this part of the testing has to be done on an amazon instance.

> My main problem is pushing the changes to the docker swarm. Should I setup my docker-swarm on a remote machine and host the application there?

If you're just using one machine you don't need the added overhead of using swarm. If you're planning to scale to a larger multi-node deployment, yes deploy to a remote machine because you'll discover sooner the gotchas around using swarm.

You need to think about how you retire old versions and bring in the latest version of your containers to the swarm which is often called scheduling.

One simple approach that can be used is:

1. Remove traffic from old running container
2. Stop old running container
3. Pull latest container
4. Start latest container
   Rinse and repeat for all running containers.

This is done in docker swarm by declaring a service. Then updating the image which can be watched as a task. For more information on the detail of this process see [Apply rolling update to swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/) and for how to do this in Amazon [updating docker containers in ecs](http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/11/11/running-docker-aws-ground-up/#update-docker-containers-in-your-ecs-cluster)

Comment: I think the only problem in your answer is removing traffic from old container. I need to deploy it without any downtime.

Comment: You need to be running multiple containers then so one container can handle the traffic while the other is updated.

Comment: I think the best way is to create a blue-green deployment